# what is wrong when i try to get list of customers from quick book online account using my web application?

Tags: quickbooks

I was using the .net sdk v2 for connecting my web application with quick book online account and getting data from qbo was working fine. But after i migrated from v2 to v3, i am getting exception message when i try to get list of customers. The error comes on following code line:

```
var qboCustomer = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer();
var qboCustomers = dataService.FindAll(qboCustomer, 1, 10).ToList();
```

error comes at second code line.

Exception Message:`There was an error reflecting type 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.IntuitResponse`
Inner Exception: `There was an error reflecting property 'AnyIntuitObjects`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error:

There was an error reflecting type 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer'......

I found that there was a conflict with the version with one of my dll(s).  In my case it was NewtonSoft.JSON.dll.   I continued to drill down the innerexceptions until I found this to be the root problem.  Resolving the version conflict with this dll resolved my problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This script will help you to get the list of customers details from the QBO.

```
QueryService<Employee> EmployeeQueryService = new QueryService<Employee>(context);
var Employee = EmployeeQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Employee MaxResults 1000").ToList();
```